# Wrap a gif with a png

Tags: imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

There are two image, one is gif, another is png. Now I need to wrap the gif image with png image. I use `ImageMagick` and I think it may work for me.

```
convert src.png input.gif -gravity Center -composite des.gif;
```

- As you see, the output is unexpected while there is a black block.
- And the `des.gif` is not animated.

[image]

left is `des.gif` the right is `input.gif`

## EDIT

Here is my test files. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-64AliLi9OnWVQyLWU3TElHNHM?usp=sharing

Comment: As we can't see the images you started with, it is practically impossible to help...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I update my question.

Comment: Please post 3 separate pictures - exactly two input images and one output image.

Comment: It seems that I can not upload there pictures. As you see, the right is `input.gif` and I use a `device frame` to wrap it.

Comment: Without your two input images, we have no way to test and figure out what the issue is. We also do the know what you mean by "wrap". Do you mean overlay on onto the other? Does one image have transparency?

Comment: @fmw42 I upload my file to `google device`. Can you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 77 frames. But the first frame is much smaller than all the rest. From Imagemagick (6.9.9.13 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra), I can see this from

```
identify input.gif

input.gif[0] GIF 216x384 216x384+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 3.20786MiB 0.010u 0:00.009

input.gif[1] GIF 1080x1920 216x384+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 3.20786MiB 0.010u 0:00.009

...

input.gif[76] GIF 1080x1920 216x384+0+0 8-bit sRGB 64c 3.20786MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Also all frames but the first are near solid green. Only the first has a circle in it.

Nevertheless, if you fix your input.gif, you can composite them so all the gif frames animate over the background png using the following command:

```
convert image.png null: \( input.gif -coalesce \) -gravity Center -layers composite des.gif
```

Note that after the coalesce all frames become 216x384. That makes the overlay frames way too small. This will make all frames larger so that they fit the background. But still all will be green exact for the first.

```
convert image.png null: \( input.gif -coalesce -resize 1080x1920! \) -gravity Center -layers composite des.gif
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#background
If using Imagemagick 7, then change convert to magick.

Comment: `magick image.png null: \( input.gif -coalesce -resize 1080x1920! \) -gravity Center -layers composite des.gif` does not work for me and it keep running and no result.

Comment: It takes a long time to resize 77 images. Be patient, it takes minutes for me. It should finish.  What is your exact version of Imagemagick. If IM 6 then use convert in place of magick. If IM 7 then you must use magick as you wrote. You may need to change the names of your images if they are not as you wrote and what was downloaded for me.

Comment: I am so sorry for the wrong test file because of I resize them before I upload to google device.Now I upload again.

Comment: Sorry again,  I put new link to question.

Comment: My os is MacOs and IM is 7

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-1 Q16 x86_64

Comment: This works fine for me on IM 7.0.7.2 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra. `magick image.png null: \( input.gif -coalesce \) -gravity Center -layers composite des.gif` The time was 1min 56 sec. Note with your new images, no resize is needed.

Comment: If you liked this answer, please consider giving it an up vote

Comment: I have a question the `des.gif`'s size is ver large. Can I do something ?

Comment: Add -layers optimize after -layers composite. For me it is causing a corrupt gif and I have reported it on the Imagemagick Discourse Server Bugs Forum. But try: `magick -limit area 0 image.png null: \( input.gif -coalesce \) -gravity Center -layers composite -layers optimize des.gif`